# Is there a standard gesture for resetting scale on a pinch-zoom canvas?

Tags: android, touch-screen, gestures, zooming

I've got an android app with a view of a diagram that can be dragged, rotated and scaled using pinch zoom and other similar gestures. Often times I find that I want to reset back to a canonical view of the diagram. Is there an agreed upon gesture for doing this besides just having a reset button? I was thinking double tapping, but I haven't seen it in other apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double tap is the default for zooming back to normal in iOS. It works in photos, safari and a lot of other apps and is encouraged in the [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/user-interaction/gestures/).

[Material guidelines](https://material.io/design/interaction/gestures.html#types-of-gestures) talk about it too:

> A pinch, or two quick taps, allows users to zoom into **and out** of
>   content.

I’m pretty sure it’s a standard expected behaviour for users by now.

Comment: Ok, I was trying to figure out why double tap felt so natural, I guess that makes sense!